# How to fit / clip svg data as src to image to its width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Ho can I make this SVG source fit as my image width and height change. It automatically adjusts the lines when width and height increase, but in case of a decrease, the text is clipped as below code.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj7s8y0w/1/)

**For me, the best solution would be to just display the text as of dimensions and add an ellipsis (...) in the end** or
the second may be a workaround to just fit the data by squeezing its original width.

```js
var text = 'It is a long <b>established fact</b> that a reader will be distracted by the <i>readable content of a page when looking</i> at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using Content here, content here, making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for lorem ipsum will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.'; 
var divCss = { 'display': 'flex', 'align-items': 'center', 'justify-content': 'center', 'margin': 'auto', 'height': '100%' };
var paraCss = { 'text-align': 'center', 'font-size': '12px', 'padding': '8px' };
var svgQ = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgQ.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "QId");
var txtElemQ = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignObject");
txtElemQ.setAttributeNS(null, "x", 0);
txtElemQ.setAttributeNS(null, "y", 0);
txtElemQ.setAttributeNS(null, "height", "100%");
txtElemQ.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "100%");
var divQ = txtElemQ.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
$(divQ).css(divCss);
var paraQ = divQ.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
$(paraQ).css(paraCss);

paraQ.innerHTML = text;
svgQ.appendChild(txtElemQ);

var Q = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgQ)
var base64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent((Q))));

$('img').attr('src', base64);
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to redraw the svg image when bounding box size changes. To do this can add a listener to window object and whenever window is resized, call the draw function again.

Comment: actually what I do is display the full text in a popup when clicked, I just want to show this a little bit better.